# Tally items using XML

Tags: excel, vba, automation, tally

I have a macro enabled excel workbook which saves the data in tally readable XML format. Currently i import the XML file in Tally manually with import data option from tally. Now i am looking for a VBA solution to automate right from excel. pleae help

calling the below line from macro in the page, tally in localhost.

finalfile is the xml file

`Call toTally("http://localhost:9000", finalFile)`

running this code from module.

```
Sub toTally(host As String, request As String)
    MsgBox request

    Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    xmlhttp.Open "POST", host, True
    MsgBox "done opening"
    xmlhttp.send request
    MsgBox "done sending"
    MsgBox (xmlhttp.responseText)
    
 End Sub
```

no entry made in tally.

Comment: Try changing the last parameter in `xmlhttp.Open "POST", host, True` from True to False. You don't want an asynchronous call here (and if you did, you would need more code anyway)

Comment: What does `xmlhttp.responseText` tell you?

Comment: post your final file string also, along with response you received

Answer (score 0):

Below code solves my problem .  Thanks a lot for all of you who took time to respond.

```
Sub toTally(host As String, request As String)
 
    Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    xmlhttp.Open "post", host, False 'host name came from calling function
    xmlhttp.send request 'file came from calling function
    
    MsgBox xmlhttp.responseText
    
 End Sub
```